# Tic-Tac-Toe check for draws JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a working Tic-Tac-Toe game, but now I need to make it check for a draw and send message to say that "It's a draw".

I tried to add a counter for the number of turns players can take, so if at the 9th turn, there's no winner, it would display the draw message. But it hasn't been working out the way I wanted to.

```
$(function() {
    //Declaring a variable to allowed turns
    var playerTurn = true;
    //Gameplay

    var count = 0;
    $("td").each(function(square){
        if ($('[index]').hasClass("X")) {
            count++;
        } else if ($('[index]').hasClass("O")) {
            count++;
        }
    })
    console.log(count);
    $("#message").html("It's a draw!")

    $('[index]').on("click", function() {
        //Prevent overlapping gameplay
        if ($(this).hasClass("X") || $(this).hasClass("O")) {
            alert("Position has been taken! Try again.")
        }
        //X will appear when it's Player 1's turn
        if (playerTurn == true) {
            $(this).addClass("X").html("X");
            $("#message").html("It's Player 2's turn");
            //Player 1's turn has ended
            playerTurn = false;
            //Check for winning combination inputs
            checkWin($('#box0'),('#box1'),('#box2'),"Player 1");
            checkWin($('#box3'),('#box4'),('#box5'),"Player 1");
            checkWin($('#box6'),('#box7'),('#box8'),"Player 1");
            checkWin($('#box0'),('#box4'),('#box8'),"Player 1");
            checkWin($('#box2'),('#box4'),('#box6'),"Player 1");
            checkWin($('#box0'),('#box3'),('#box6'),"Player 1");
            checkWin($('#box1'),('#box4'),('#box7'),"Player 1");
            checkWin($('#box2'),('#box5'),('#box8'),"Player 1");

        //O will appear when it's Player 2's turn
        } else if (playerTurn == false) {
            $(this).addClass("O").html("O");
            $("#message").html("It's Player 1's turn");
            //Player 2's turn has ended

            playerTurn = true;
            //Check for winning combination inputs
            checkWin($('#box0'),('#box1'),('#box2'),"Player 2");
            checkWin($('#box3'),('#box4'),('#box5'),"Player 2");
            checkWin($('#box6'),('#box7'),('#box8'),"Player 2");
            checkWin($('#box0'),('#box4'),('#box8'),"Player 2");
            checkWin($('#box2'),('#box4'),('#box6'),"Player 2");
            checkWin($('#box0'),('#box3'),('#box6'),"Player 2");
            checkWin($('#box1'),('#box4'),('#box7'),"Player 2");
            checkWin($('#box2'),('#box5'),('#box8'),"Player 2");
        }
    });

    //Function for chechking winning patterns is declared
    function checkWin(box1, box2, box3, player) {
        if (player == "Player 1") {
            //Conditions to win for by Player 1
            //A combination of three positions must all be true
            if ($(box1).hasClass("X")==true && $(box2).hasClass("X")==true &&
                    $(box3).hasClass("X")==true) {
                //Message is sent to declare the winner
                $("#message").html(player +" has won!");
            }
        }
        //Conditions to win for by Player 2
        //A combination of three positions must all be true
        if (player == "Player 2") {
            if ($(box1).hasClass("O")==true && $(box2).hasClass("O")==true &&
                    $(box3).hasClass("O")==true) {
                //Message is send to declare the winner
                $("#message").html(player +" has won!");
            }
        }
    }

    //Clear the grid after a winner is declared
    $('#restart').click(function() {
        //All Xs and Os are removed
        $('td').removeClass("O X").html("");
        //The winner from the last round will start
        $("#message").html("Let's play!")
    });
});
```

Comment: Can i see the HTML or a jsfiddle of this. Or place your counter inside the click function and have an IF statement...

Answer (score 1):

You’re only checking for a draw at the start of the game when nothing’s happened yet. Check every move, like when you check for the winner.